# Evaluate Math Expression - Syntax

Tags: java, class

**What is the right syntax to evaluate the expression?**

```
public double evaluate(){
    String ans = (expressionOne.getValue())+""+(SignOperator.getName())+""+expressionTwo.getValue()+"";

    return Double.parseDouble(ans);
}
```

expressionOne for example can be X and his value is 5.5 and expressionTwo for example can be Y and  his  value  is 9.0.
when i`m trying to evaluate some expression i get : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.5+9.0"

The second part is when i want to print some expression i created toString()

```
public String toString() {
    String ans = expressionOne.toString()+""+SignOperator.getName()+""+expressionTwo.toString()+"";
    return ans;
}
```

For Exmaple:

```
    Variable x = new Variable ('x',5.5);
    Variable y = new Variable ('y', 3.5);
    Constant  nine= new Constant (9.0);
    Operator plus=new Operator('+');


    BinaryExpression xPy = new BinaryExpression(x, plus, y);
    BinaryExpression xP9 = new BinaryExpression(x, plus,nine);
```

When i print xPy is will give me x+y.
and when i print xP9 - it will give me x+9 ( becuase nine is constant ). 

 How in one toString i can check if the expression is constant( just a number ) or a variable ( as in the example ) - how to detect it?  .

**EDIT**
as you can see, there is two kinds of BinaryExpression - one of them xPy - x and y is two varaibles, if i want to evaluate them it will give me for example ( 3.0+5.0 ) but if i will print them it will give me x+y, for the second example  xP9 - if i will evaluate it will give me (3.0+9.0) but if i will print them it will give me ( x + 9.0 ) becuase the nine is Constant ( see the question ) .

Thanks.

Comment: none package, i want to create my own evaluate, i created the classes above.

Comment: Double.parse("5+9") is indeed invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For evaluation you need to evaluate yourself, `Double.parseDouble()` is not going to evaluate the expression for you and then return the result

`Double.parseDouble()` takes a string that is expressible as double (You know "1223.456" is indeed a double value tough it is in string form while "123.45+153.4" is not because it contains "+" character that makes it invalid double value)

***How in one toString i can check if the expression is constant( just a number ) or a variable***

You can use `Character.isDigit()` method to know whether expression is a number(digit) or variable(non digit)

[See the `Character` class API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Comment: as you can see, there is two kinds of BinaryExpression - one of them xPy - x and y is two varaibles, if i want to evaluate them it will give me for example ( 3.0+5.0 ) but if i will print them it will give me x+y, for the second example  xP9 - if i will evaluate it will give me (3.0+9.0) but if i will print them it will give me ( x + 9.0 ) becuase the nine is Constant ( see the question ) .

Comment: for that you need to override `toString` method of `Constant` and `Operator` class

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a String describing the operation in evaluate() ?
You should do the operation on doubles there.

I would suggest adding in class Operator a method :

```
double apply(double left, double right)
```

with appropriate implementation classes.

```
Operator plus = new Operator('+')
{
    double apply(double left, double right) { return left + right; }
};
```

Then you would just call apply in your evaluate method

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help you where in it tries to evaluate the entire expression and provide you the result.

I understand that you are trying to write a Expression Evaluator engine where in you could use Script Engine as used in the below post.

[Usage of script engine for evaluating string expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score -1):

Look into `infix` and `postfix` notations if you want to make your arithmetic evaluator. For example:

In fix notation:

```
y = 4 + 9 + 3 / 6 * 5;
```

Post fix notation:

```
y = 4 9 3 6 / 5 * + +;
```

**Refrence**
http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/index.htm